# php.ini file in AWS cloud9

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide

I am trying to edit my php.ini file in cloud9. I tried uploaded another php.ini file into the root folder but it isn't reading it. I also tried to access the file from the command line but it looks like Amazon is blocking it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apache is not configure to use the php.ini file located at the root of your workspace. The file is located at `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`.

My favorite option is to create a symbolic link. have a look at this page, step by step guide to configure the php.ini file: [How to configure php.ini on AWS EC2 Cloud9?](https://www.lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-configure-phpini-on-aws-cloud9/)